# check if value exists in an Object containing multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I have an Object that contains multiple Objects

```js
const edges = {
         edge1: {source: "Horse", target: "4_2_0_0_0f"},
         edge2: {source: "Horse", target: "4_2_0_0_0x"},
         edge3: {source: "Horse", target: "4_2_0_2_1h"},
         edge4: {source: "Horse", target: "4_2_4_0_4z"},
         edge5: {source: "Horse", target: "4_2_1_0_0p"},
....}
```

Now I want to check whether `edge2: {source: "Horse", target: "4_2_0_0_0x"}` exists in `edges` or not.
What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried and why wasn't it fast enough for you?

Comment: Use the `Array.some()` method with a callback function that checks for the properties you want.

Comment: Do you only care about the `edge2` property? Then it's even easier. `if (edges.edge2.source == 'Horse' && edges.edge2.target == '4_2_0_0_0x')`

Answer (score 1):

You can [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one of array elements matches your condition. Before that you will need to convert object you array with [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const edges = {
  edge1: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_0_0_0f"
  },
  edge2: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_0_0_0x"
  },
  edge3: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_0_2_1h"
  },
  edge4: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_4_0_4z"
  },
  edge5: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_1_0_0p"
  },
}

function existsEdge(source, target) {
  return Object.values(edges).some(v => v.source === source && v.target === target)
}

console.log(existsEdge('Horse', '4_2_0_0_0x'))
```

This is effective if you wish to check only once. If you wish to check multiple times, consider using different data structure with fasters checks. Example using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const edges = {
  edge1: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_0_0_0f"
  },
  edge2: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_0_0_0x"
  },
  edge3: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_0_2_1h"
  },
  edge4: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_4_0_4z"
  },
  edge5: {
    source: "Horse",
    target: "4_2_1_0_0p"
  },
}

const index = new Set(Object.values(edges).map(v => `${v.source}:${v.target}`))

function existsEdge(source, target) {
  return index.has(`${source}:${target}`)
}

let result = undefined
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  result = existsEdge('Horse', '4_2_1_0_0p')
}

console.log(result)
```